# Replacing part of an href attribute using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, href

I'm trying to make a simple website that creates dynamic links for Google Classroom depending on your authUser number. I'm doing this since Google Classroom takes a good 6-10 seconds before loading classes.

**Basically what I want is a script that replaces part of an href to the user's authUser number.**

**So `classroom.google.com/u/authUser/c/fakeclass` and `authUser = 1`**

**Would become `classroom.google.com/u/1/c/fakeclass`**

I prefer replacing part of the link instead of creating a link, to keep the script clutter free and the code simple. I would also prefer not using jQuery or other JS libraries simply because I don't understand.

I've tried a bit but could only get it to replaces it in one href attribute

```js
authUser = 1 //--> For simplicity sake only
let newUrl = document.getElementById("link").href;
newUrl = newUrl.replace("test", authUser);
document.getElementById("link").href = newUrl;
```

```html
<a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/test/c/fakeclass1" id="link">Fake Class 1</a>
<a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/test/c/fakeclass2" id="link">Fake Class 2</a>
<a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/test/c/fakeclass3" id="link">Fake Class 3</a>
```

**As you see it only replaces it in the first link and I understand why but how can I make it so the code replace it for every link?**

I've tried `for` but I don't think I did it right.

Comment: Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML. Fix that first, then figure out a selector string that matches the `<a>`s, then iterate over them

Comment: get the link by `querySelectorAll` and replace them with. a loop,